# How can i use an AXIOS POST reponse from one component in another component?

Tags: reactjs, json, redux, react-redux, axios

Everything seems in order, the API is already functioning perfectly and returning a response with a JSON.

I need to get this JSON from the component that makes the post and gets the response to a component made to order this info and render it.

So far I have been able to access the response and get the arrays of information in the same component where the Axios post is, whenever I try to use the JSON from another component it won't recognize it

Should I combine these two components and make one?  also, I have seen people using redux to store props globally and then using it in all of the ccomponents with no problem of recognition or prop-drilling.

I have read docs about redux. I understand how it works but as new as I am in it,I don't have a clue how to implement it

**UPLOADER AND AXIOS POST COMPONENT**

```
class SendFile extends Component {
  
    state = {
 
      // Initially, no file is selected
      selectedFile: null
    };
    
    // On file select (from the pop up)
    onFileChange = event => {
    
      // Update the state
      this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    
    };
    
    // On file upload (click the upload button)
    onFileUpload = async () =>  {
    
      // Create an object of formData
      const formData = new FormData();
    
      // Update the formData object
      formData.append(
        "file",
        this.state.selectedFile,

      );
    
      // Details of the uploaded file
      console.log(this.state.selectedFile);
    
      // Request made to the backend api
      // Send formData object
      const headers = {
        'access-token': "ACCES-TOKEN",
        'filename': "file-name"
      }
      const diagnoseRequest = await axios.post("API",formData,{ 
        headers:headers
    });
    
    console.log(diagnoseRequest.data.diagnose);
    };
    
    // File content to be displayed after
    // file upload is complete
    fileData = () => {
    
      if (this.state.selectedFile) {
         
        return (
          <div>            
<p>Nombre del archivo: {this.state.selectedFile.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
         null
        );
      }
    };
    
    render() {
    
      return (
        <Container>
            <Uploader>
                <input   id="uploadBtn" accept="application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                <button onClick={this.onFileUpload}>
                Cargar Archivo
                </button>
            </Uploader>
          {this.fileData()}
        </Container>
      );
    }
  }
 
  export default SendFile;
```

**RENDERING COMPONENT**

```
function PdfSection({divider,img, title, data, text, subtext, text2, subtext2, text3, subtext3}) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Top>
             <img  className="divider" src={divider}/>

            </Top>
            <Bottom> 
            <LeftSide>
                <img className='description' src={img}/>
            </LeftSide>
            <RightSide>
            <Header>
              <h1>{title}</h1>
            </Header>
            <Body>
               <h2>{data}</h2>
               <h3>{text}</h3>
               <p>{subtext}</p>
               <h3>{text2}</h3>
               <p>{subtext2}</p>
               <h3>{text3}</h3>
               <p>{subtext3}</p>
            </Body>
            </RightSide>
            </Bottom>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default PdfSection
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: You need either prop drill, redux or Providers. Learning Redux isn't in the scope of SO, and you can find many resources to learn it online.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use react-query or apollo

Comment: redux is giving me a hard time, I guess I will have to push through! thanks @Aron

Comment: I'll keep it in mind! thank you @mttetc